# why rails server is not working on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created the new rails project and trying to run it without doing any changes. I am using the power shell in windows 10. When I am running the `rails s` command its not starting the server. Please see attached image. I have highlighted the installed ruby version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is there in the output, you do not have a rails app to start a server for, you can create a new app with:

```
rails new <name-for-your-app>
```

Follow along [this tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application)
to help you get started with rails.

Comment: No, this is not the case. I created the app first then entered into the folder and then I am trying to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will work or you are missing something which is required to run rails server

```
bin/rails server
```

Comment: No, its not working.  I am getting the below error. Executed this script on windows power shell.

```bin/rails : The term 'bin/rails' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bin/rails server
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bin/rails:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Can you create new rails project again? And attach the screenshot here?

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar error when I am not in rails project directory. Seems you are out of directory.
Please run those full commands in powershell

```
cd c:/
rails new testapp
cd testapp
rails s
```